# Bootstrap 3 - push/pull layout alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the below layout on mobile:

```
-------------
|     1     |
-------------
|  2  |  3  |
-------------
|     4     |
-------------
```

I would like to lay it out like this on desktop:

```
-----------------------
|     |    1    |     |
|  2  |---------|  3  |
|     |    4    |     |
-----------------------
```

Is that possible? Thanks :)